# Why does the for loop in selection sort have n-1 steps instead of n? C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, selection-sort

I have the following attempt to write a selection sort in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10], k, i, j, n, aux;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    k = a[0];
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n-1; j++)
            if (k > a[j])
                k = a[j];
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n-1; j++)
            if (k == a[j]) {
                aux = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = aux;
            }
        k = a[i + 1];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
        cout << a[i];
    return 0;
}
```

From my tests it returns sorted arrays, so I think it's correct.

But I also have to explain why the main for loop of the sort only takes n-1 steps instead of n. Could anyone explain the "why" part to me?

Comment: In `C++` array indexes go from `0` to `n-1` so your loops should do the same: `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) ...`

Comment: You overwrite the bounds of the array on the very first read loop if `n` is 10.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just typed a random numer, I know 10 is too small for most cases.

Comment: No, what I'm trying to say is what was said by Galik.  Arrays are indexed starting from 0, not 1.  When `n` is `0`, writing to `a[n]` on the last iteration of that loop overwrites memory.

Comment: @Galik I know that, it's just how I got used to doing it because I was taught this way in school. Bt still, if I use a for from 0 it doesn't go n-2?

Comment: @BiancaStan Your school is wrong.  Arrays in C++ start at 0.  Accessing an array beyond its bounds is not only wrong, it is a memory overwrite and in some cases, causes for security breaches.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, I just thought about the overwriting part. Thanks for the advice. But still, how do I explain the fact that it only takes the for loop n-1 steps instead of n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider how many steps are required if `n` is 1.

Basically, you don't need to sort the first element.

Answer (score 3):

The sorting is done by comparing *pairs* of elements.

How many pairs are there in an array of N elements? (hint: N-1)

[This animation](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms) might help explain how the algorithm works.